Azure DevOps dependency between different runs of a build pipeline
I have a requirement where I want a build pipeline run to wait if a previous run for the pipeline is still "inProgress".
For example, in below image a run is already in progress, now a new run should wait or depend on this run to complete (either fail, cancel, or succeed).

I have explored below options:

"exclusive lock" as a check in Environment. (not very flexible)
invoke rest api as a check in Environment. (could not find much in Azure documentation on how to use result to handle check )
or have a stage in yaml pipeline for checking previous runs status may be in a loop as a bash or python step. (this seems to be a flexible approach which can be customized.)

Any pointers on the right approach to address this requirement will really help.

As per Define approvals and checks - Exclusive Lock:

In the YAML file for the pipeline, specify a property called lockBehavior. This can be specified for the whole pipeline or for a given stage.

Example:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

lockBehavior: sequential

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: Job
    steps:
    - script: sleep 20
      displayName: 'Sleep for 20 seconds'

Running 2 builds one right after another, this is displayed in the second build:

Clicking on View button:

EDIT 1 - 2024-09-25
I ran more tests. It seems that the lockBehavior works only at the stage level, not the whole pipeline (this might be a bug, though).
Consider the following pipeline with 2 stages:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

lockBehavior: sequential

stages:
  - stage: A
    jobs:
    - job: Job
      steps:
      - script: sleep 20
        displayName: 'Sleep for 20 seconds'

  - stage: B
    dependsOn: A
    jobs:
    - job: Job
      steps:
      - script: sleep 20
        displayName: 'Sleep for 20 seconds'

Running 2 builds one right after another, we can see that stage A in the second build is run before stage B in the first build:


Even though my answer is probably not very helpful for the OP as he's using multiple stages, I'll keep it here as it might be useful in cases where there is a single stage per pipeline.

If lockBehavior is ignored at the pipeline level, then based on the documentation, that sure sounds like a bug to me.

Related: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Exclusive-lock-configured-at-pipeline-le/10754019?q=lockBehavior

Related: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-run-pipeline:-A-check-of-type/10750217?q=lockBehavior


a new run should wait or depend on this run to complete

Currently, Azure DevOps doesn't support it if your pipeline has multiple stages. Azure pipeline allocates agents based on jobs instead of builds. And the dependency is job/stage level instead of build level. If you want such feature, you can submit a feature request on Azure DevOps Developer Community and share the link here. Then others who want the same feature can follow it and add comments to increase the priority.
For your case, there is a workaround you can refer to, although it's not perfect.

In the first stage of your pipeline, run REST API Definitions - Update to update the value of queueStatus to paused. When it is paused, builds in the queue will not be started by the system.

Run REST API Definitions - Get to check the current queueStatus, if it is paused, which means that there is already a running build, exit and fail the current build.
If the value is enabled, change it to paused.


In the last stage of your pipeline, run REST API Definitions - Update to update the value of queueStatus to enabled.

You must use stage dependency to ensure the order of the step1 and step2.

Example YAML:


lockBehavior: sequential

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

stages:
- stage: First
  jobs:
  - job: first_job
    displayName: 'Pause new runs'
    steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            $token = "{PAT}"
            $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
            $head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
            $url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/build/definitions/{BuildDefinitionID}?api-version=7.1"
            $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $head
            if ($response.queueStatus -eq "enabled") {
              $response.queueStatus = "paused"
              Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method PUT -Headers $head -Body ($response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10) -ContentType application/json
            } else {
                exit 1
            }


- stage: A
  dependsOn: First
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    displayName: A1
    steps:
      - script: echo "This is A1"

- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    displayName: B1
    steps:
      - script: echo "This is B1"

- stage: Last
  jobs:
  - job: last_job
    displayName: 'Enable new runs'
    steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            $token = "{PAT}"
            $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
            $head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
            $url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/build/definitions/{BuildDefinitionID}?api-version=7.1"
            $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $head
            $response.queueStatus = "enabled"
            Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method PUT -Headers $head -Body ($response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10) -ContentType application/json


Result:


build1 gets the agent.
build2 comes before build1 finishes the first stage. When build2 gets the agent, it will fail in the first stage. Build1 gets the agent back and keeps running until completing the last stage.
build3 comes after Build1-Firststage finished, it will wait for the agent until build1 is completed.




I used Rest API approach but the flow is different. I allowed artifact build stage to complete, then a Rest API validation stage to check if any previous run status is "inProgress" and fail the validation stage.  User can first take decision on the already inProgress run and after it completes then re-run the validation stage in current pipeline. I will also post my solution as an answer.

Thanks for your update. It's a good workaround. For my suggestion, we can make some improvements. You can set up a self-hosted agent. Run the first stage on the self-hosted agent. Instead of failing the stage, you can loop the API to check the queueStatus if its value is paused and exit the loop when its value is enabled.  So that there will be no failed build, and the build will run one by one.

we have self-hosted agent and I thought of using loop to check status instead of failing the stage. The only concern I had was the compute cost of the VM while the loop runs (we did not want to run it infinitely). May be we can plan to run loop for a couple of hours to avoid failure and finally fail the validation if no one from team attends the already inProgress run if the run is waiting for some manual approval.

“The only concern I had was the compute cost of the VM“, that’s right, that’s why I didn’t mention it in my answer. These suggestions are for reference only, you can adjust them according to your actual situation. For the method mentioned in my answer, if the interval between two consecutive builds is more than two minutes, then it will be a good method and there will be no failed builds. Because 2 minutes is enough for PowerShell to run the API in the first stage. In my actual test, it does not exceed 1 minute.

Here is what worked for me.
stages:
- stage: ExistingBuildCheck
displayName: Checking if there is an existing build inProgress

jobs:
  - job: GetInProgressBuilds
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - script: |        
        set -e  

        json_response=$(curl --location --request GET 'https://dev.azure.com/{Org}/{Project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions=$(System.DefinitionId)&branchName=$(Build.SourceBranch)&statusFilter=inProgress&api-version=7.1' --header 'Authorization: Bearer $(System.AccessToken)')

        # escape character can create parsing issues
        refined_json=$(echo $json_response| sed 's/\\/\\\\/g')

        ## get count of all Runs retrieved where status is inProgress. 
        read -r count_inProgress_runs <<< $(python -c "import json; data = '''$refined_json'''; parsed = json.loads(data); \
                                                    count_inProgress_runs = parsed['count']; \
                                                    print(count_inProgress_runs )" \
                                          )
         # exiting run counts as 1 so count > 1 confirms existing inProgress run other than the current run
        if [ "$count_inProgress_runs " -gt 1 ]; then
          echo -e "\033[1;31m Another run is currently in progress. Wait for it to finish or cancel it before starting a new one."
          exit 1 # exit with error to fail stage
        else
          echo -e "\033[1;32m There is no other run inProgress except this one!"
          exit 0 # success.
        fi            

The above stage is injected between build stage and deploy stage.
I allowed artifact build stage to complete, then a Rest API validation stage to check if any previous run status is inProgress and fail the validation stage. User can first take decision on the already inProgress run and after it completes then re-run the validation stage in current pipeline.
